# Проверка сервиса на thread-safe

Tags: java, concurrency

Подскажите, пожалуйста, является ли thread-safe следующая реализация сервиса.

```
public class TaskReport {

    private final String taskID;
    private final Date startTime = new Date();
    private Date endTime = null;
    private final List<String> report = new ArrayList<String>();
    private volatile boolean completed = false;

    public TaskReport(String taskID) {
        this.taskID = taskID;
    }

    public String getTaskID() {
        return taskID;
    }

    public Date getStartTime() {
        return startTime;
    }

    public Date getEndTime() {
        synchronized ( endTime ) {
            return endTime;
        }
    }

    public void append(String entry) {
        synchronized ( report ) {
            report.add(entry);
        }
    }

    public List<String> getReport() {
        synchronized ( report ) {
            return report;
        }
    }

    public boolean isCompleted() {
        return completed;
    }

    public void setCompleted() {
        this.completed = true;
        synchronized ( endTime ) {
            this.endTime = new Date();
        }
    }

}

public class TaskReportService {

    private final ConcurrentHashMap<String, TaskReport> tasks = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public TaskReport get(String key) {
        return tasks.get(key);
    }

    public void create(TaskReport report) {
        tasks.putIfAbsent(report.getTaskID(), report);
    }

    public void delete(String key) {
        tasks.remove(key);
    }

}
```

Насколько я понимаю [ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) обеспечивает потокобезопасность только атомарных операций, т.е. еще необходима дополнительная синхронизация содержимого. А не может ли в такой ситуации возникнуть дедлока?

Comment: не проше ли поставить `syncronized` перед функциями `get`, `create` и `delete`

Comment: Для данной реализации проще, спасибо. Перед этим у меня переменная tasks была public static, соответственно access методов не было, отчего и возник вопрос.

Comment: @SaidolimDjuraev: не думаю, что это хорошая идея. ConcurrentHashMap не блокируется на `get`, т.к. в этом нет необходимости. Незачем эту блокировку создавать искусственно.

Comment: И второй минус синхронизации методов сервиса в том, что для изменения состояния объекта к нему будет необходимо обращаться только через сервис. Тогда как при синхронизации самого объекта, можно безопасно обращаться через ссылку, которая все равно передается в метод create().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В этом коде много проблем с потокобезопасностью, хотя многие вещи зависят от того, как он используется. Например, `TaskReportService.create`:

```
public void create(TaskReport report) {
    tasks.putIfAbsent(report.getTaskID(), report);
}
```

Вас точно устраивает ситуация, что созданный снаружи кем-то `TaskReport` может быть помещён в map, а может и не быть? Причём вы никак не узнаете, был ли он помещён. Я могу снаружи сделать:

```
TaskReport report = new TaskReport("foo");
service.create(report);
report.append("bar");
```

При этом совершенно неизвестно, сохранилась ли строчка `"bar"` или нет. Допустим вы всегда вызываете `service.create` для свежесозданного `TaskReport`, а потом его не используете. Зачем тогда его создание выносить наружу, раз это может привести к потенциальным проблемам? Не проще ли сделать метод `getOrCreate`?

```
public TaskReport getOrCreate(String key) {
    TaskReport report = tasks.get(key);
    if(report != null)
        return report;
    // Нету - создаём
    TaskReport newReport = new TaskReport(key);
    TaskReport oldReport = tasks.putIfAbsent(key, newReport);
    if(oldReport != null) {
        // Ой, кто-то в другом потоке только что создал с тем же ключом вперёд нас
        // Выкидываем наш новый и возвращаем тот, что есть
        return oldReport;
    }
    // Возвращаем свежесозданный
    return newReport;
}
```

Теперь если вы будете для создания `TaskReport` пользоваться только этим методом, у вас гарантировано не будет двух репортов для одного ключа, по крайней мере пока вы не начнёте удалять и создавать с тем же ключом.

Кстати, если у вас Java-8, вышеприведённый метод будет однострочным:

```
public TaskReport getOrCreate(String key) {
    return tasks.computeIfAbsent(key, TaskReport::new);
}
```

Далее — класс `TaskReport`. Тут тоже многое зависит от того, как он используется. Попытки синхронизации подсказывают, что один и тот же `TaskReport` может использоваться из нескольких потоков одновременно. Вот такой код абсолютно бесполезен:

```
public Date getEndTime() {
    synchronized ( endTime ) {
        return endTime;
    }
}
```

Вы совершенно ни от чего не защищаетесь. А вот это ещё хуже:

```
synchronized ( endTime ) {
    this.endTime = new Date();
}
```

На это вроде даже FindBugs ругается. Бессмысленно синхронизоваться по объекту в поле и присваивать в это же поле другое значение. Надо сперва понять, от чего вы защищаетесь. Если вы не собираетесь менять содержимое объектов `Date` (например, вызывая `Date.setTime()`), то вам нечего защищать. В крайнем случае объявите поле `endTime` как `volatile`, чтобы изменения были видны в других потоках сразу. Синхронизация здесь излишня и бесполезна.

Аналогично бесполезно вот это:

```
synchronized ( report ) {
    return report;
}
```

Когда вы уже вернёте `ArrayList` наружу, блок синхронизации завершится и дальше всё зависит от того, что будет делать внешний пользователь с этим списком. Если он собрался обходить его итератором (например, чтобы вывести строки в интерфейсе пользователя), вас не спасает ни синхронизация в `append`, ни в этом методе. Вы можете словить `ConcurrentModificationException` или чего похуже. Вас не спасёт даже оборачивачивание списка в `Collections.synchronizedList`. Здесь я вижу три варианта:

- Если вы часто пишете и редко читаете, проще вернуть копию:

  ```
  public List<String> getReport() {
      synchronized ( report ) {
          return new ArrayList<>(report);
      }
  }
  ```
- Если вы редко пишете и часто читаете, можно воспользоваться `CopyOnWriteArrayList`:

  ```
  private final List<String> report = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<String>();
  ```

  В этом случае синхронизация не нужна вообще (ни в append, ни в геттере). Просто верните `report` в геттере. Можно обернуть в `Collections.unmodifiableList` для безопасности.
- Если вы часто пишете и часто читаете, но вам не нужен случайный доступ, воспользуйтесь `ConcurrentLinkedDeque`:

  ```
  private final Collection<String> report = new ConcurrentLinkedDeque<String>();

  public Collection<String> getReport() {
      return Collections.unmodifiableCollection(report);
  }
  ```

  В этом случае тоже в `append` синхронизация не нужна.

Comment: Осознал. Большое спасибо за подробное описание.